# Generate random numbers without loops

Tags: r, performance, loops, random

I'm trying to reduce as much as I can the execution time of a function that sums the output of a sequence of Bernoulli trials.

This is my working-but-slow approach:

```
set.seed(28100)
sim <- data.frame(result = rep(NA, 10))
for (i in 1:nrow(sim)) {
  sim$result[i] <- sum(rbinom(1200, size = 1, prob = 0.2))
}
sim
# result
# 1     268
# 2     230
# 3     223
# 4     242
# 5     224
# 6     218
# 7     237
# 8     254
# 9     227
# 10    247
```

How could I obtain the same result without a for-loop?

I tried this...

```
set.seed(28100)
sim <- data.frame(result = rep(sum(rbinom(1200, size = 1, prob = 0.2)), 10))
sim
# result
# 1     269
# 2     269
# 3     269
# 4     269
# 5     269
# 6     269
# 7     269
# 8     269
# 9     269
# 10    269
```

But clearly the argument of `rep()` is executed only once.

Comment: I'll point you to my answer for explanation, but the one-liner solution is `rbinom(10, size = 1200, prob = 0.2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binomial distribution is defined as the sum of Bernoulli trials.

```
# this line from your question
sum(rbinom(1200, size = 1, prob = 0.2))
# is equivalent to this
rbinom(1, size = 1200, prob = 0.2)

# and replicating it
replicate(expr = sum(rbinom(1200, size = 1, prob = 0.2)), n = 10)
# is equivalent to setting n higher:

        ### This is the only line of code you need! ####
rbinom(10, size = 1200, prob = 0.2)
```

It takes about 0.01 seconds for 100,000 simulations and 0.12 seconds for 1M simulations on my (rather slow) laptop.

Modifying @eipi's nice benchmarking, this is about 700-900 times faster than the other methods (now with bug fixes!)

```
          expr     min      lq       mean  median      uq     max neval cld
         binom   1.324   1.377   1.607959   1.413   1.931   2.306    10 a  
     replicate 716.300 737.200 756.288641 749.900 765.300 812.400    10  b 
        sapply 706.300 743.300 778.863587 763.800 853.500 860.300    10  b 
 matrixColSums 838.800 870.000 893.813083 894.800 907.500 978.200    10   c
```

Benchmark code:

```
nn = 10000
n_bern = 1200
library(microbenchmark)
print(
    microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
        replicate =
            replicate(nn, sum(rbinom(
                n_bern, size = 1, prob = 0.2
            )))
        ,
        matrixColSums =
            colSums(matrix(
                rbinom(n_bern * nn, size = 1, prob = 0.2), ncol = nn
            )),
        sapply = sapply(
            1:nn,
            FUN = function(x) {
                sum(rbinom(n_bern, size = 1, prob = 0.2))
            }
        ),
        binom = rbinom(nn, size = n_bern, prob = 0.2),
        times = 10
    ),
    order = "median",
    signif = 4
)
```

Comment: if you look at my `replicate` code in your answer, you can see I don't have the correct values for the arguments (1 and 12 instead of 1200 and 1). I was in the process of moving toward something like your answer but I guess I must have run timings while I was in the middle of that, rather than beforehand. Anyway, `replicate` isn't any faster than the other two methods, and yours is obviously the way to go. I just want to let you know so you could correct the code and the timings for the `replicate` approach (I've already corrected my answer).

Comment: It's funny, when I parametrized the `nn` for the benchmarking I also began to pull out a `n_bernoulli = 1200`, but when I got to your code you just had the 12 - I thought you were doing something fancy accounting for it elsewhere - and I didn't take any time to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

How about like this:

```
set.seed(28100)
sims <- 10
n <- 1200
r <- rbinom(n*sims, size = 1, prob = 0.2)
r <- matrix(r, ncol=sims)
colSums(r)
```

For me it is about twice as fast with 100,000 simulations (6 vs 13 seconds), but R. Schifini's and eipi10 solutions are a little faster (~5.5 seconds)

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(28100)
nsim=10
sim = data.frame(result=replicate(nsim, sum(rbinom(1200, size=1, prob=0.2))))

sim
```

> ```
>    result
> 1     268
> 2     230
> ...
> 9     227
> 10    247
> ```

Here are some timings of the various methods with 10,000 simulations:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  replicate = {nsim=10000
  data.frame(result=replicate(nsim, sum(rbinom(1200, size=1, prob=0.2))))},
  matrixColSums = {
    sims <- 10000
    n <- 1200
    r <- rbinom(n*sims, size = 1, prob = 0.2)
    r <- matrix(r, ncol=sims)
    data.frame(result=colSums(r)) },
  sapply = data.frame(result=sapply(1:10000, FUN = function(x) {sum(rbinom(1200, size = 1, prob = 0.2))})),
  times=10
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
>     replicate 584.2389 597.5571 615.7545 614.0977 630.7354 648.8328    10  a 
> matrixColSums 655.0608 664.2053 684.0069 682.1868 702.1426 713.0240    10   b
>        sapply 589.9830 610.5784 626.8738 629.2161 642.2589 660.6092    10  a
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
sim = rep(NA, 10)
sapply(sim,FUN = function(x) {sum(rbinom(1200, size = 1, prob = 0.2))})
```

Result:

```
[1] 216 231 234 249 249 236 255 251 231 244
```

Then convert to a data frame

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization is the key.

The main time saver (at least for big `n`) is the use of `sample`.

e.g. for

```
n <- 1e7
sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)
```

takes about 0.2 sec, while

```
for(i in 1:n) sample(0:1, 1)
```

takes about 24 sec. Vectorised operations can often replace loops, but knowing when and where depends on the familiarity with the available function for your needs.